# SDL Events Memory Leak

Tags: c, events, memory, sdl, memory-leaks

Are there any know methods or functions in SDL known to cause memory leaks?

I noticed for my program that as time when on, .1 MB of memory kept on being tacked onto the program's memory usage (ie. an extra '.4 MB' were added in exactly 3 minutes).

I commented out all of my surface drawing/bliting functions; pretty much just isolated the main game loop to the event structure and screen flipping, ex:

```
// .. Intilize
char quit = 0;
Uint8* keystate = NULL;
SDL_Event hEvent;
while (!quit) 
{
    // .. Code

    while (SDL_PollEvents(&hVvent)) {
        keystate = SDL_GetKeystate(NULL);
        // .. Event processing
    }

    // .. More Code

    if (SDL_Flip(screen) == -1)
        return 1

    SDL_Delay(1);
}   
// .. Cleanup
```

Comment: I don't know of any leak in SDL. Chances are that it is in your code. You should keep on stripping your program until the leak disappears or you can post the whole leaking code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favourite tool to check for memory leaks is [Valgrind](http://www.valgrind.org/).
After compiling your code, just run the following command:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./executable
```

After finishing, check the output for memory leak information.
The tool can be more verbose, by issuing the -v flag

Answer (score 1):

```
valgrind --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./executable
```